# Runtime model generation using django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an application that needs to generate its models on runtime.
This will be done according to the current database scheme.
How can it be done?
How can I create classes on runtime in python?
Should I create a json representation and save it in a database and then unserialize it into a python object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to read this http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Here is example how to create python model class:

```
Person = type('Person', (models.Model,), {
    'first_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
    'last_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
})
```

You can also read about python meta classes:
 - [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)
 - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html
 - http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/metaclass_1.html

Comment: and how can I generate them based on the database itself?

Comment: You would have to look at code of inspectdb, and based on that create model classes for each table. http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py

Comment: Why you want to generate those models at runtime ? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm trying to create some graphical user interface for the models.

Comment: What this UI will do ? Will it create just model classes ? or also tables in database ?

Comment: It will also create tables in the database, use south to migrate them, ect.

Answer (score 2):

You could base yourself on the legacy database support of django which allows you to obtain django models from the definitions found in the database :

See here : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs

In particular,

```
manage.py inspectdb
```

allows you to create the classes in a file. You should then be able to import them on the fly.

That said, it seems to me that you are on a risky path by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an application that needs to generate its models on runtime.

Take a look at the [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py) for the `inspectdb` management command. `Inspectdb` "Introspects the database tables in the database pointed-to by the NAME setting and outputs a Django model module (a models.py file) to standard output."

> How can I create classes on runtime in python?

One way to do this is to use the functions provided by the [`new`](http://docs.python.org/library/new.html) module (this module has been deprecated in favor of [`types`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#module-types) since 2.6).

> Should I create a json representation and save it in a database and then unserialize it into a python object?

This doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

**PS:** All said you ought to really rethink the premise for creating classes at runtime. It seems rather extreme for a web application. Just my 2c.